# Spring DAO modular project structure questions

Tags: java, spring, maven, orm

I'm doing a refactor of my project to be Spring (I'm a Spring n00b) based and use an ORM, I have a couple a applications that access the same database.  What I'd like to do in my project structure is have a maven module for my DAOs (project crush-dao) and have each of my apps pull in that module.  In the past when I've worked with Spring the bean definition were in my webapp so referencing the dao beans were all together.

With this structure, how would I reference the crush-dao beans from my app's (e.g. App A, App B) beans.xml? And would a property configurer bean at the App X level, would my xml in crush-dao know to inherit those properties?  Since App X is including crush-dao as a dependency would App X include crush-dao's beans.xml explicitly through a classpath reference?

Does this seem like a logical structure? Trying to get it right the first time... Thanks

EDIT: Or is it more logical to have the contents of crush-dao beans.xml in each App's xml? I was trying to avoid duplicating code/config but this seems more logical than what I was asking above, right?

Comment: you can have an entity layer as one project, and by making it a dependency on your main app, you'll be able to include those DAOs.